# Is it possible to save the contents of a text area as a file with .java extension on azure?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, azure, azure-storage

I have to design an azure application where people can write java code and save them on the azure cloud. I am using asp.net to build the application.

I had the idea of displaying a text area to the user where he can write his java code and then saving it as a .java file automatically when he hits the save button. Is this possible? Is there a way to retrieve the contents of the text area and then saving the contents in a file with .java extension? Or is there a better way of doing so?

I do not have much knowledge about this and am still researching. Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Would you argument why you unaccepted the answer after 6 days?
What was not correct?
You could have commented, or updated question if you didn't understand something.

Comment: cool, and 10x. I'm glad that it worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are working with Java and are already familiar with the Java language, why don't you just use the [JAVA Tooling](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/java/) to build your Azure application entirely in Java?

Other than that, here are answers to your questions:

> I had the idea of displaying a text area to the user where he can
>   write his java code and then saving it as a .java file automatically
>   when he hits the save button. Is this possible? Is there a way to
>   retrieve the contents of the text area and then saving the contents in
>   a file with .java extension?

Yes, it is complete possible. You have to use the ASP.NET server control [TextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.aspx). You can use it in that way:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tbMyJavaContent" TextMode="multiline" />
```

On the codebhind you just need to get the Text property of the control:

```
string javaFileContent = this.tbMyJavaContent.Text;
File.WriteAllText("path_to_file.java", javaFileContent);
// here the logic to upload that file to a Blob storage
```

Then save that content on to a file. However you shall not just save it locally! You shall always use Windows Azure Blob (or Table) storage to save your files. Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6821162/uploading-multiple-files-to-azure-blob-storage) for an example of how to upload file to Windows Azure Blob.

As for whether there is a better way for achieving your goal, I don't know. If the task is that: your end users must have the tools to write their own code, which in result will be saved to a local plain text file (with extension .java). Then, even if there are other solution, they will all move around having a textarea where user can write, and than saving the content of this textarea to a local file. At the end don't forget to upload your file to a Blob for durable persistance.

If you are using asp.net MVC framework, it is even easier. You just need a texarea and a Controller action which takes a single parameter of type string and name - the name of the textarea. Something like (the View):

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("SaveContent", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
<textarea name="taJavaContent" rows="20" cols="40"></textarea>
}
```

The Controller (HomeController.cs):

```
public ActionResult SaveContent(string taJavaContent)
{
   string tmpFileName = SomeMethodToGetLocalFileName();
   File.WriteAllText(tmpFileName, taJavaContent);
   SomeMethodToUploadLocalFileToABlob(tmpFileName();
}
```

Hope this helps!